# How to call an action on double click at a custom NSCell in Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

i have an NSTableView with custom view cells from NSCell

i'm now trying to get the double click action with this code

```
[theTableView setDoubleAction:@selector(myDoubleClick:)];
```

and i have the method set like this:

```
- (void)myDoubleClick:(id)sender{
 NSLog(@"double click");
}
```

when i double click the cells nothing happens and the nslog is not showing a thing.

maybe it is something with my customs cell.

any suggestions on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Should do this on IB selecting the row and setting the column bindings there's the option co choose a selector from one of your controllers.